# NSDate formatString sometimes return nil

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate

I created a class that has a NSDate object which is created from a value in a JSON. The string value is like: `2016-12-02T13:51:23+01:00`. Most of times the string is successfully converted and the date object is created, but SOMETIMES application crashes while trying to force unwrap on optional value, I don't know where. The line of code that sometimes fails is:

```
self.creationMoment = stringDateFromJson == nil ? NSDate() : NSDate(string: stringDateFromJson, formatString: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ")
```

Does anybody have some idea?

Comment: Can you show string, which can't be converted to date?

Comment: You need to provide a lot more detail. Which line of code actually causes the error? Update your question with more relevant code and provide specific examples that fail.

Comment: The line of code that fails is the the one that I posted with the exactly value that I wrote. The example that I give you is one of the real cases.

Comment: how do you mean _sometimes_? neither the JSON parser nor the date formatter is a drama queen who goes on strike _sometimes_... what is the input what you could not parse as a date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I redeclared the `creationMoment` variable as Swift `Date` instead `NSDate` and this problem never appear again, it could be an Apple bug...

Answer (score 0):

it could be possible that your object is of NSNull class?
in this case you can use:

```
self.creationMoment = stringDateFromJson.isKind(of: NSNull) ? NSDate() : NSDate(string: stringDateFromJson, formatString: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ")
```

Comment: This can't be the issue because if `stringDateFromJson` actually were `NSNull`, then the code would crash if different ways.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your stringDateFromJson sometimes might be empty. Therefore the == nil is going to be false, and when trying to create the NSDate with an empty string a nil is returned. Try to change your code to something lie this 
`let isNotValidStringDate =  stringDateFromJson == nil || stringDateFromJson.isEmpty
self.creationMoment = isNotValidStringDate ? NSDate() : NSDate(string: stringDateFromJson, formatString: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssh")`

Comment: the example in the question with the date "2016-12-02T13:51:23+01:00" was a real case: when app crashed, I look into jsonDateString and I found that string, so It was not empty. Moreover, json date is never empty because of back-end auto-generating date at creation moment of the entity...